# Does putting constraints decrease the required size to store my data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, constraint, check-constraints

I would like to know if putting check constraints decrease the required column size or not? For example, when I create an *int* column and a check constraint on it to store the numbers between 100 and one million, does it decrease the required size for storing the data?

Comment: No. The answer is no.

Comment: Integer's size is always the same, only VARxxxx rows can store variable sizes.

Comment: ... Unless you use row compression (and that also includes page compression) whte most type are variable in length - ish. But the length doesnt depend on check constrains, but the actual value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The answer is no. Integer's size is always the same, Unless you use row compression (and that also includes page compression) whte most type are variable in length - ish. But the length doesnt depend on check constrains, but the actual value.